# ConstraintViolationException VS DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am writing a Spring app, and it seems that when I run into database errors, sometimes Hibernate's `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown and sometimes Spring's `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown.  Is there a reason one might be thrown and not the other?  Do they mean different things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you execute Hibernate calls via the `HibernateTemplate`, then Spring will translate any Hibernate exceptions (e.g. `ConstraintViolationException`) into the Spring exception hierarchy (e.g. `DataIntegrityViolationException`). If you don't use `HibernateTemplate`, then the native Hibernate exceptions will go through. Both are `RuntimeExceptions`, so don't need explicit exception handling, so it's not always obvious which one you're going to see.

Comment: I'm not using `HibernateTemplate`, yet I get Spring's wrapper exception only when the primary key is violated. Other unique key violations result in Hibernate's exception. The code is identical--only the type of key that gets violated matters.

Comment: Are you using the @Repository annotation on your DAO?