# ConstraintViolationException during Test, but DataIntegrityViolationException when Running

Tags: hibernate

I'm testing my in-memory DBUnit app to violate a constraint.

I see `ConstraintViolationException`s when running the test locally. However, when actually deploying and testing my app, I see `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246803/constraintviolationexception-vs-dataintegrityviolationexception), the `DataIntegrityViolationException` error occurs due to: `If you execute Hibernate calls via the HibernateTemplate`.

I'm speculating (without fully knowing) that this might be happening for my test environment.

How can I check if my test setup is using the `HibernateTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, whats happening is that the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` will be converting the `ConstraintViolationException` that is thrown during testing into the Spring `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

The `ConstraintViolationException` will be caught in the unit tests because this is the generic javax.validation/hibernate.validation exception, but when you deploy the project properly, Spring converts it to an exception that it understands.

(This is mostly speculation on my part, if I'm wrong I'll delete this)

To test if I'm right, remove your `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` from your config, redeploy and see if you get a `ConstraintViolationException` thrown

Comment: I searched for `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` but found 0 results

Comment: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor

Comment: Did you ever sort out your problem?